# What standard SQL isolation levels do the SQLite isolation levels correspond to?

Tags: transaction, sqlite, concurrency, isolation-level

There are four standard SQL isolation levels:  Read Uncommitted,  Read Committed, Repeated Read, and Serializable. (c.f. *Database System Concepts* 6ed.)

In SQLite, there are three isolation levels: DEFERRED, IMMEDIATE, or EXCLUSIVE. They control how the required read/write locks are acquired. See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/using-sqlite/9781449394592/ch04s07.html

> By default, all transactions (including autocommit transactions) use the DEFERRED mode.
> Under this mode, none of the database locks are acquired until they are required. This
> is the most “neighborly” mode and allows other clients to continue accessing and using
> the database until the transaction has no other choice but to lock them out. This allows
> other clients to continue using the database, but if the locks are not available when the
> transaction requires them, the transaction will fail and may need to be rolled back and
> restarted.

> IMMEDIATE attempts to acquire a reserved lock immediately. If it succeeds, it
> guarantees the write locks will be available to the transaction when they are needed,
> but still allows other clients to continue to access the database for read-only operations.

> The EXCLUSIVE mode attempts to lock out all other clients, including read-only clients.
> Although the IMMEDIATE and EXCLUSIVE modes are more restrictive to other clients, the
> advantage is that they will fail immediately if the required locks are not available, rather
> than after you’ve issued your DDL or DML commands.

I was wondering if it is possible to make some correspondence between the four standard SQL isolation levels and the three SQLite isolation levels?

- Does DEFERRED mean exactly serializability isolation level, but only applies to transactions which consist of only one statement not more than one?
- Does IMMEDIATE mean exactly read uncommitted isolation level, which prevents dirty write but not dirty read?
- Does EXCLUSIVE mean exactly serializability isolation level?

Answer (score 4):

DEFERRED, IMMEDIATE, and EXCLUSIVE are not isolation levels. All three modes ensure the serializable isolation level. (SQLite's transcations are always serializable because it actually serializes them; there is a single, database-wide lock.)

IMMEDIATE takes the equivalent of a write lock at the beginning of the transaction; this prevents a deadlock when two concurrent read-only transactions try to update to a write lock. EXCLUSIVE is useful when you want to lock the database without actually writing.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how the three are serailizable level, and elaborate more about how  the three are different?

Comment: "are serializable" would imply that these modes *are* isolation levels, which they are not. The transaction modes and the isolation levels are completely orthogonal.